# can't uploading large files with php

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize

i'm testing a website on my localhost not on the server
in php.ini max file size is 128 mb but i can't upload a 26 mb flv file it doesn't give me an error or anything the page just refreshes and nothing happens it doesn't upload but small large files are uploaded successfully any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in php.ini, .htaccess and web-server config. Make sure you're editing correct php.ini.

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 8M 
ok now i know why thanks but about hosting do they have the same limits ? how could i know or change them ? via support tickets ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to ask to the hosting support via ticket. The limits depends from your hosting plan.